# How do I get a floppy to appear on the left pane in Explorer

Tags: windows-10, usb, windows-explorer

OS: Windows 10 20H2

I don't know if this was a problem on earlier versions as I've only just started using a USB floppy drive for getting data off an old oscilloscope.

If I attach any USB storage device like a memory stick or an external hard drive or a phone, it appears on the left pane of Windows Explorer.  All except for the floppy drive.  If I attach a floppy drive, it only appears on the right pane but not the left.

Is there a registry entry or something to get the floppy drive to appear on the left pane?

Answer (score 0):

> If I attach a floppy drive, it only appears on the right pane but not
> the left.

I hooked up my USB A: Drive with a floppy disk in it.

That is the way Windows File Explorer works and I don't think I would risk a Registry setting to change its operation. I looked and do not see such a reasonable setting.

xPlorer2 shows A: on the left side and Tree Size shows A: with C:

So I think your machine is working perfectly well and just use it as it is.